# pandas pivot table descending order python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataset that i read in with

```
data = pd.excel('.../data.xlsx)
```

then i organized everthing with pivot table

```
newdata = data.pivot_table(index=["Block", "Conc", "Replicate"], columns=["Name"], values="F532Mean-B532") '
```

**the Pivot table looks like this (the actual table's format is a little bit different than this, i typed the table in manually here:**

```
Block     conc      replicate     nameA    nameB   nameC ..     

  1                     
            0           1           2225     12     333   
                        2           3        423    52
                        3           53       88     239
           0.01         1           24       53     923
                        2           454      253    53
                        3           4        5      23
           10           1           34       53     923
                        2           44       253    53
                        3           11       49     232
   2
            0           1           234      634     39 
  .....
```

**everything looks good except i want the 'Conc' column to be in descending order, so instead of 0, 0.01, 10  , i would like it to be 10, 0.01, 0.**

```
 Conc 
  10

  0.01

   0
  ...
```

i have searched online and found a couple of posts with this kind of code:

```
  key1 = newdata.index.labels[0]
  key2 = newdata['Concentration'].rank(ascending=False)
  sorter = np.lexsort((key2, key1))
  sorted_df = newdata.take(sorter)

  sorted_df.to_excel('pivottable.xlsx')
```

the it gave me

```
KeyError: 'Concentration'
```

i think the problem is that the online examples are all only 2 levels, here i have more than 2 level. what's a way around this?

Comment: @Andy Hayden   a new problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your pivot_table is a MultiIndex. You want to sort by levels in a MultiIndex, for which you should use [`sortlevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                       nameA  nameB  nameC
Block conc  replicate
1     0.00  1           2225     12    333
            2              3    423     52
            3             53     88    239
      0.01  1             24     53    923
            2            454    253     53
            3              4      5     23
      10.00 1             34     53    923
            2             44    253     53
            3             11     49    232

In [12]: df.sortlevel(["Block", "conc"], ascending=[True, False], sort_remaining=False)
Out[12]:
                       nameA  nameB  nameC
Block conc  replicate
1     10.00 1             34     53    923
            2             44    253     53
            3             11     49    232
      0.01  1             24     53    923
            2            454    253     53
            3              4      5     23
      0.00  1           2225     12    333
            2              3    423     52
            3             53     88    239
```

*Note: the `sort_remaining` ensures that the other levels aren't also sorted, although here it's not an issue (as it's already sorted on replicate).*

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the data frame using `sort_values()`.

```
df
Out[10]: 
   Block   conc  replicate  nameA  nameB  nameC
0      1   0.00          1   2225     12    333
1      1   0.00          2      3    423     52
2      1   0.00          3     53     88    239
3      1   0.01          1     24     53    923
4      1   0.01          2    454    253     53
5      1   0.01          3      4      5     23
6      1  10.00          1     34     53    923
7      1  10.00          2     44    253     53
8      1  10.00          3     11     49    232

df.sort_values('conc',axis=0,ascending=False)
Out[11]: 
   Block   conc  replicate  nameA  nameB  nameC
6      1  10.00          1     34     53    923
7      1  10.00          2     44    253     53
8      1  10.00          3     11     49    232
3      1   0.01          1     24     53    923
4      1   0.01          2    454    253     53
5      1   0.01          3      4      5     23
0      1   0.00          1   2225     12    333
1      1   0.00          2      3    423     52
2      1   0.00          3     53     88    239
```

Update:
Pivoted df will have multi-level columns. So, find the column name by `newdata.columns` you can use the multilevel column names in tuples (lev1,lev2)

Update: 
You have multi column index in pivoted table and trying to sort with one of the column. `sort_index()` works if reset other two index and if you reset `conc` you could use `sort_values()`

Comment: I tried but i got error , i do'nt think i can do that to a pivot table.  i want my pivot table output for 'Conc' in descending order.

Comment: @Jessica: were you able to pivot your table?

Comment: yes, the table above is from my pivot table, i dont know how to copy paste table here , so i typed it in manually, that's why the format looks a bit different

Comment: So, problem is you are missing the `multi-level columns`. find the names or your `newdata` dataframe.