# Panda Pivot - Sort by Column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have data that look like this from a panda pivot table:

```
df:
    sum
    PrctChange
    Year        2011        2012        2013        2014        2015
    CountryName                 
    Argentina   17.378744   5.750719    7.923327    -0.062792   8.889681
    Belize      0.515086    -1.278683   16.819298   -0.104759   10.539688
    Burundi     0.000000    inf         3.209646    2.165577    6.411365
```

I'm trying to sort it by the 2015 data so that it's listed as Belize, Argentina and Burundi (2015 values in descending order)

I've seen some very relevant and similar questions but they don't seem to work for me

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309652/pandas-sort-multiindex-pivot-table), I tried:

```
pivot_sorted = df_values(('PrctChange', 2015))
```

and got this error:

```
KeyError: ('PrctChange', 2015)
```

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590599/pandas-pivot-table-descending-order-python), I tried:

```
pivot_sorted = df.sortlevel(["2015"], ascending=[False], sort_remaining=False)
```

I didn't get an error but there was no sorting.

And finally, I tried this

```
pivot_sorted = df.sort_values(by=(df['2015']), ascending=False,inplace=True)
```

and got this error:

```
KeyError: '2015'
```

Can anyone please assist? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try df.sort_values(by='2015', ascending=False,inplace=True)?

Comment: @A-Za-z thank you for the suggestion. i got another key error: 2015 :-(

Comment: post the output of `df.index`

Comment: Thank you @TedPetrou This may be part of the problem for which I can not find a solution. I did that and got a list of the countries: 'Index(['Argentina', 'Belize', 'Burundi'],
      dtype='object', name='CountryName')''

Comment: sorry if this is a nag.... just dont know if tags work in the edit comment area. @TedPetrou

Comment: No its not part of the problem. I meant for you to output the columns. My mistake. Show us the output of `df.columns`

Comment: No, thank you, @TedPetrou
here it is:
`MultiIndex(levels=[['sum'], ['PrctChange'], ['2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=[None, None, 'Year'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The columns are a three level MultiIndex object. You must use all three levels to select a column.

```
df.sort_values(('sum', 'PrctChange', '2015'), ascending=False)
```

Comment: so close! thank you so much @ted petrou! Is there any way it can be sorted in descending order though?

Comment: Just add `ascending=False`